# How to convert (4,3) array into (4,1) array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
myarray = array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 2]])
myarray.shape = (4,3)
```

Result should look like that:

```
MUTAG_graph_struct[0][0]
Out[112]: 
(array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), array([[(array([[ 5],
       [22],
       [ 5],
       [ 5],
       [20]], dtype=uint8),)]], dtype=[('values', 'O')]), array([[array([[2]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[1, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[2]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[2]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[2]], dtype=uint8)]], dtype=object))

result = MUTAG_graph_struct[0][0][2]
```

so in my case, I want output like as above.One array with array elements.
And it should give then:

output:`MUTAG_graph_struct[0][0][2]`

```
array([[array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[0, 2, 3]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[0, 1, 3]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[0, 1, 2]], dtype=uint8)], dtype=uint8)]], dtype=object)
```

can you please suggest how to do that?
I am using python3.

I tried `np.stack` , `np.concatenate` but can't figure-out the problem?

Comment: `myarray.reshape(4,1,1,3)` - it's the real  shape of your result

Comment: The pipeline I am using for Graph classification demands shape of array in this format. So I wanted to create shape as it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output doesn't have correct bracketing. If ypu are looking something which looks like

```
array([[[[1, 2, 3]]],

       [[[0, 2, 3]]],

       [[[0, 1, 3]]],

       [[[0, 1, 2]]]])
```

You may try doing `myarray.reshape(4,1,1,3)`.

Comment: Hi Anant, it is not same as I want. As I little know, can we use something row iteration concept?

Comment: Please update the required output? The bracket opening and closing do not match.